# Reactjs, how to import at build time?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a react app that uses a large json file as a textstore. Rather than having the copy scattered all over the app, it is in one neat file.

To use the text within the app I use a component (below) that will retrieve the text from the json file.

```
<Text path='Homepage.Title' />
```

This component will simply return the string into the jsx.

This works absolutely fine and I have no issues with it. My question is about when this returning is done.

I had assumed this would happen at build time. Since the json file is constant I would expect react to place all the strings inline.

However, I'm not sure if this is actually the case. I tested this by putting a console.log in the function that gets the string from the json.. and sure enough it is called in the browser.

Is react going into the json file and retrieving the string while rendering?
Why isnt react smart enough to only do this once at build time? - how do I tell it that's what I want?

Obviously my preference is to have this happen during the build, so if there is a way of doing this please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're expecting React to know anything about the app-bundling process or the contents of the different modules comprising the rest of your webapp.  if you want to perform a task at bundle-time, you need to configure your bundler (webpack, in this case) to do that task.